# Lowest TTL that can be set in BIND9

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm having trouble finding it this answer, but what is the lowest TTL that can be set on an A or CNAME record in BIND9?

Comment: The lowest TTL that you can technically set, or the lowest TTL that will be honored elsewhere on the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to 0, but that doesn't mean a caching DNS server will honor that request.
Many servers have a default minimum TTL for records, and the cache server will not allow the TTL to be less.